# [flow，react]Why can't I use flow to the react project like this?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I think the flow should also be statically checked when referenced in other react components, but not...
Is it wrong with my use of the flow?

```
// This is the Icon.jsx file code 

// @flow

import * as React from 'react';

import { Icon } from 'antd';

type Props = {
  type?: string
};

export default class FGIcon extends React.Component<Props> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Icon
        {...this.props}
      />
    )
  }
}

class testFlow extends React.Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <FGIcon type={222222}/>
    )
  }
}
```

I used `<FGIcon type={222222}/>` under the current file, the flow check is normal.

> Cannot create `FGIcon` element because  number [1] is incompatible with  string [2] in property `type`.Flow(InferError)

but,

```
// This is the Button.jsx file code 


// @flow

import * as React from 'react';

import { Button } from 'antd';

import { Icon } from '../';

export default class FGButton extends React.Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          {...this.props}
        />
        <Icon type={178954666}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

By referencing the Icon react component in Button.jsx files, the flow cannot check the type attribute.

Why can't I use flow to the react project like this?

Comment: To clarify, is the `Icon` import in `Button.jsx` referring to `FGIcon` in `Icon.jsx`? I'm not sure if this is an issue, but the code has `FGIcon` as a default export but `Icon` is being imported as named. I would also try writing some invalid Flow code in `Button.jsx` that doesn't have any dependencies (e.g., `var x: string = 1234;`) just to check that Flow is running correctly in the file.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your reminder, yes, the Icon referenced in the Button.jsx file is FGIcon。My FGIcon component directory is named Icon。

like this:
 + Icon(dir)

   +  Icon.jsx

   + index.js

Comment: And the Flow is running correctly in the Button.jsx, However, the imported Icon component flow check is invalid.

Comment: I can't see anything immediately that suggests at what's going wrong. If you're able to link to a repo, I could run it on my end to try to figure it out. Otherwise, I would recommend debugging using the `type-at-pos` and `get-def` CLI commands on `Icon`. An example problem may be that `Icon` is being imported as `any` because a Flow annotation (`// @flow`) is missing in the file that's exporting `Icon`.